# TextWriter closed unexpectedly after async call in Azure webjob

Tags: c#, async-await, azure-webjobs

I've created a simple Azure WebJob that calls an async Task and am trying to use the `TextWriter` to log some information. 
Writing to the log before the call to the async task is fine but after the call the `TextWriter` is closed. In the sample code below, I am just calling `Task.Delay()` to demonstrate.

It does not matter if I change the `await log.WriteLineAsync("")` calls to `log.WriteLine("")`

```
public class Program
{
    // Please set the following connection strings in app.config for this WebJob to run:
    // AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage
    static void Main()
    {
        JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
        JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
        host.Call(typeof (Program).GetMethod("DoJobNow"), new { value = "Hello world!" });
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }


    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public async static void DoJobNow(string value, TextWriter log)
    {
        await log.WriteLineAsync("Write with textwriter");
        await log.WriteLineAsync("Write with textwriter again - still open");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        await log.WriteLineAsync("TextWriter is closed?? Exception here!");

    }
}
```

When I run this code locally, I get a `System.ObjectDisposedException` on the last log call and if I comment on the `Task.Delay` line, it works fine!
Why is this?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507384/azure-webjob-textwritter-logger-being-disposed-in-the-middle-of-my-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the return type of DoJobNow to return a Task. The calling thread will cause the TextWriter to be disposed

```
[NoAutomaticTrigger]
public async static Task DoJobNow(string value, TextWriter log)
{
    await log.WriteLineAsync("Write with textwriter");
    await log.WriteLineAsync("Write with textwriter again - still open");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    await log.WriteLineAsync("TextWriter is closed?? Exception here!");
}
```